# "It's time ... 'verb'/'verb-ed' ..."

Tags: idioms, modality

> It's time colleges **helped** you compare apples to apples.
>
> (The Boston Globe)

If the time is a present moment, why does the journalist use "help" in the past tense? Or is "helped" subjunctive?

Answer (score 6):

My first reaction here was that this cannot be a *past subjunctive*, because with BE in the first or third person singular the same idiom calls for simple past WAS rather than subjunctive WERE:

> It is time I *was* in bed.
>   It is time he *was* going.

However, a little quick Google-Booking turned up a handful of such uses as *time he were* and *time I were* down to about World War I. Moreover, a common variant of the idiom employs the modal *should*, which often replaces *irrealis* subjunctives:

> It is high time this war should be ended.

So I think, Yes, this is a *past subjunctive*, employed to express a proposition which is not a fact (but should be). And like the past subjunctive in other cases, it has lost its distinctive forms for 1st and 3rd person singular BE:

> If he was/were here he would have something to say about that.

Answer (score 2):

The expression *it's time* can be followed by **to + infinitive, for + object + to + infinitive,** or **subject + past tense verb.**

1. *It's time to go.*
2. *It's time for me to go.*
3. *It's time she went home.*
4. *It's time I went home.*

There is no difference in meaning, other than who is being referred to -- and all 4 variations refer to present time; in #1, the referent could be the speaker or one or more listeners, depending on the context.  To my ear, the **subject + past tense verb** construction sounds more judgmental or critical: in #3, the critical tone is directed towards the third person, a female, and in #4 reflexively towards the speaker him- or herself.